# Asynchronous express handlers with fork

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous

Consider the following express program

```js
const express = require("express");
const { fork } = require('child_process');

const API_PORT = 3001

const app = express()
app.listen(API_PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${API_PORT}`));

app.get("/", async (_req, res) => {
    var compute = fork("child.js")
    compute.send('start');
    compute.on("message", result => {
        res.send(result)
    })
})
```

and it's accompanying `child.js` file:

```js
process.on("message", (msg) => {
    var date1 = new Date();
    var start_sec = date1.getSeconds();

    setTimeout(() => {
        var date2 = new Date();
        var fin_sec = date2.getSeconds();
        process.send("Starting at: " + start_sec + " / Finished at: " + fin_sec);
    }, 5000);
});
```

When I open two browsers in quick succession to `localhost:3001/`, I expect them to both return in about 5 seconds. For instance, if I open one browser at time=13 and the second at time=14, I would expect the browsers to show `Starting at 13 / Finished at 18` and `Starting at 14 / finished at 19` respectively. Instead, they show `Starting at 13 / Finished at 18` and `Starting at 18 / Finished at 23`.

**Why did the second request wait for the first to finish? How would I modify this code to achieve the expected result?**

Comment: I think this is likely caused by Chrome not wanting to send the exact same request to the exact same host from the exact same browser until the first one responds.  Try adding a second request handler and see if Chrome will send the request in a more timely fashion if you send the second request to a different path, say `/1` and `/2` (with identical code in both request handlers).  This is just an experiment to figure out why it's doing this.

Comment: FYI, see this: [Google Chrome queued request one by one when multiple requests to a localhost node application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53236124/google-chrome-queued-request-one-by-one-when-multiple-requests-to-a-localhost-no).  This is confirmation that Chrome is queuing the 2nd request until the first responds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Chrome specific "feature".  If you send two identical requests to the same host, Chrome will queue the second request until the first one responds.  Other browsers (such as Firefox) don't do this.  Presumably, somebody thought they were protecting from unnecessarily overloading a server by waiting until the first request is done.

You can likely work around this by supporting more than one route that does the same thing and then using separate routes for your first and second request such as `/1` and `/2`.  You could experiment with a query parameter on the route and see if Chrome will bypass the feature if the query parameter is different such as `/?a=1` and `/?a=2`.

---

In running my own test, it appears that the query parameter is enough of a difference in the requests for Chrome to avoid the queuing and let them both run in parallel.

I confirmed the problem with these two URLs:

```
http://localhost:3001/
http://localhost:3001/
```

I avoided the problem with these two URLs:

```
http://localhost:3001/?a=1
http://localhost:3001/?a=2
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, I managed to get :
`Starting at: 53 / Finished at: 58` and `Starting at: 54 / Finished at: 59` on 2 firefox tabs.

But if you do that with 2 chrome browsers, the second chrome tab wait for the first one to complete. I do not know the exact explanation, but that's how Chrome handles multi-tab requests.

Answer (score -1):

This behaviour caused by `express`. If you add some `console.log` before fork, you'll see that the request is blocked, until the response is sent to client.

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  console.log('A');
  var compute = fork("child.js")
  compute.send('start');
  compute.on("message", result => {
    res.send(result)
  })
})
```

You'll see one A, then the response appears in your browser1, and then you'll get A for browser2.

To achieve your goal, you need to establish websocket connection, or use [server push to client](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/node-js-can-http-2-push-b491894e1bb1).

If you change code to this

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  var compute = fork("child.js")
  compute.send('start');
  compute.on("message", result => {
    console.log(result)
  })
  res.status(200).send('OK')
})
```

You'll see output in console just like you wish it.

```
Starting at: 36 / Finished at: 39
Starting at: 38 / Finished at: 41
```

But again, in express HTTP you can't send response to client for second time.

```
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  var compute = fork("child.js")
  compute.send('start');
  compute.on("message", result => {
    res.send(result) // Won't work!!!
  })
  res.status(200).send('OK')
})
```

Comment: I do not think this is caused by Express.  I think it's caused by Chrome.  Express doesn't block just because a request handler is "in process" and hasn't yet sent its response.  This is more likely Chrome deciding that it's going to queue the 2nd browser request to the same host and path as the first until the first responds.